# Is Event broker pass events to event processors or event processors always listen to the event Broker

Tags: architecture, event-driven, event-driven-design

I am new to Event Driven Architecture and trying to understand this. I was searching in google. I have studied for sometime. 
In some sites they said

> Event processors always listen to the Event Broker and receive the event.

And in some sites

> Whenever the event broker receive any event from event creators, it passes the event to the all subscribers.

I am in confusion. Which is correct? please help me with some explanation. please help me with some google references.

Any help would be appreciated. Please respond with whatever knowledge you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the two statements are correct. They just say the same thing with different terms and from a different perspective.

A consumer can *pull* events out of the broker or the broker can *push* events to the consumer.

The first statement is written from the point of view of the *"consumer"* or *"event processor"*:

> Event processors always listen to the Event Broker and receive the event.

Sounds like consumers are idle and waiting to be notified by the broker. So in this case it seems to be the broker pushing events to the consumers.

The second statement says the same thing, just from the point of view of the broker:

> Whenever the event broker receives any event from event creators, it passes the event to the all subscribers.

In other words, in the moment a new event occurs, and the event broker knows about it, it broadcast it to all interested *"subscribers"* (or consumers, or event processors).

So this is the same as before, consumers, subscribers or event processors are all the same concept. They are all idle and waiting to be notified by the broker when something happens.

So, as far as I'm concerned both statements mean the same.